# SQL give me the courses where users inside are less than 30

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I'm looking for a solution to get a list of courses that have less than `30` users inside.
I've looked everywhere, but I can not get through it. I'm not very practical with mySQL.

I have 3 tables:

```
1) TABLE course
_ID, COURSECODE

2) TABLE course_user:
_ID, ID_COURSE, ID_USER

3) TABLE user:
_ID
```

How can I get the `COURSECODE` only of courses that have less than `30` users?

Thank you very much ... sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
SELECT COURSECODE, COUNT(user:_ID) FROM TABLE1, TABLE3
WHERE 
   TABLE3.user:_ID = TABLE2.course_user:_ID
AND
   TABLE2.ID_COURSE = TABLE1.ID_USER
GROUP BY COURSECODE
HAVING COUNT(TABLE2.ID_USER) < 30
```

Please avoid using meaningless or confusing names. EG `user: _ID`, `ID_USER`, `course_user: _ID`

For further infromation about this query, I reccomend you to take a look at:

- [COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Documentation
- [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2014/ms177673(v=sql.120)) Documentation
- [HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2014/ms180199(v=sql.120)) Documentation

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at HAVING clause: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

Something like this:

```
select Course.COURSECODE, count(course_user.ID_USER) from course
     join course_user on course_user .ID_COURSE = course._ID
     group by Course.COURSECODE
     having count(course_user.ID_USER) < 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use :

```
SELECT c.COURSECODE
  FROM course_user cu 
  LEFT JOIN course c on (c.id = cu.id_course)
  LEFT JOIN user u on (u.id = cu.id_user)
 GROUP BY c.COURSECODE
 HAVING count(cu.id_user) < 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.COURSECODE, count(u.id) as userCount
FROM course_user cu JOIN course c on (c.id = cu.id_course) JOIN user u on (u.id = cu.id_user)
GROUP BY c.COURSECODE
HAVING userCount < 30;
```